# MySQL query to fetch most recent record

Tags: mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I've got four tables. The structure of these tables is shown below (I am only showing the relevant column names).

```
User (user_id)
User_RecordType (user_id, recordType_id)
RecordType (recordType_id)
Record (recordType_id, record_timestamp, record_value)
```

I need to find the most recent `record_value` for each `RecordType` that a given user has access to. Timestamps are stored as seconds since the epoch.

I can get the RecordTypes that the user has access to with the query:

```
SELECT recordType_id 
FROM User, User_RecordType, RecordType 
WHERE User.user_id=User_RecordType.user_id 
AND User_RecordType.recordType_id=RecordType.recordType_id;
```

What this query doesn't do is also fetch the most recent Record for each RecordType that the user has access to. Ideally, I'd like to do this all in a single query and without using any stored procedures.

So, can somebody please lend me some of their SQL-fu? Thanks!

Comment: I've added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  This question has been answered dozens of times on StackOverflow.  Follow the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Record.recordType_id,
  Record.record_value
FROM
  Record
INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT
    recordType_id,
    MAX(record_timestamp) AS `record_timestamp`
  FROM
    Record
  GROUP BY
    recordType_id
  ) max_values
ON
  max_values.recordType_id = Record.recordType_id 
AND 
  max_values.record_timestamp = Record.record_timestamp
INNER JOIN
  User_RecordType
ON
  UserRecordType.recordType_id = RecordType.recordType_id
WHERE
  User_RecordType.user_id = ?
```

Comment: If the recordType_id column in the Record table is unique we don't need the `AND max_values.record_timestamp = Record.record_timestamp` condition, right?

Comment: If that is the case, then why do you ask for "the most recent record_value", "fetch the most recent Record for each RecordType" and talk about the timestamps? This implies there is more than one record per recordtype... please decide!

Comment: Sorry Dan, you're quite right. I was confusing the recordType_id column with the record_id column. My mistake. Your solution works well -- many thanks.